# Como customizar o response_model de um endpoint?

Tags: python, fastapi

Estou usando a FastAPI do Python e preciso retornar um JSON assim:

```js
{
  "@xmlns": "url",
  "@versao": "versao",
  "tpAmb": 2,
  "verAplic": "verAplic",
  "cStat": 200,
  "xMotivo": "Cadastro de equipamento realizado com sucesso",
  "dhResp": "2021-10-02T12:44:49-03:00",
  "NSUMovto": "mov"
}
```

Criei o `BaseModel` no FastAPI assim:

```py
class TRetRecepcaoLeitura(BaseModel):
    xmlns: str
    versao: str
    tpAmb: int
    verAplic: str
    cStat: int
    xMotivo: str
    dhResp: str
    NSU: str
```

Sé que esse *schema* não consegue colocar o `@xmlns`, aparece somente o `xmlns`. Existe alguma maneira de colocar esse `@` no *schema* a ser retornado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não diretamente, por conta da própria linguagem não permitir.

Para customizar tipos mais complexos e/ou adicionar informações adicionais do campo definido no *schema*, você pode utilizar o [`Field`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/) do [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/). No seu caso mais especificamente, basta declarar um `alias`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class TRetRecepcaoLeitura(BaseModel):
    xmlns: str = Field(..., alias="@xmlns")
    versao: str = Field(..., alias="@versao")
    tpAmb: int
    verAplic: str
    cStat: int
    xMotivo: str
    dhResp: str
    NSU: str
```

Quando a documentação for gerada, você terá este resultado:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta